Can not find thrust/universal_vector.h in the Thrust library which is included in the CUDA Toolkit
I am currently using Thrust to transfer data between GPU and CPU. But when I include <thrust/universal_vector.h> in my code, using CMake to configure the project, "fatal error : No such file or directory" popped out.
I don't need to install Thrust after CUDA and CUDA Toolkit installation, as Nvidia says:

Installing the CUDA Toolkit will copy Thrust header files to the standard CUDA include
directory for your system. Since Thrust is a template library of header files, no further
installation is necessary to start using Thrust.


I check the thrust directory included from the CUDA Toolkit installation in the include directory on my computer, I didn't find several files which are existed in the official Thrust GitHub repository, such as universal_allocator.h, universal_ptr.h, universal_vector.h.

Here is my CMakeLists.txt:
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)

project(hellocuda LANGUAGES CXX CUDA)

add_executable(main main.cu)
target_include_directories(main PUBLIC ../../include)
target_compile_options(main PUBLIC $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:--extended-lambda>)
target_compile_options(main PUBLIC $<$<COMPILE_LANGUAGE:CUDA>:--expt-relaxed-constexpr>)


I can't just download the Thrust repository and include in the CMakeLists.txt, because I get other dependencies missing. Simply copy the files universal_allocator.h, universal_ptr.h, universal_vector.h to the Thrust directory included in the CUDA directory also didn't work with lots of errors.

I also check my CUDA version with nvcc --version:
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2020 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Mon_Oct_12_20:09:46_PDT_2020
Cuda compilation tools, release 11.1, V11.1.105
Build cuda_11.1.TC455_06.29190527_0



I actually successfully run some CUDA code using CMake, so I think the CUDA version should be no mistake.

The CUDA 11.1 toolkit shipped with Thrust 1.9.10. The features you are asking about were not added to Thrust until Thrust 1.12 was released. You would need to upgrade to a newer CUDA toolkit (maybe 11.4 or newer) for those features

There are release notes which you could have and should have consulted: https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust/releases

"Simply copy the files universal_allocator.h, universal_ptr.h, universal_vector.h to the Thrust directory included in the CUDA directory also didn't work with lots of errors." These files are only defining the API. The implementatins needed to compile these features are hidden in some detail directories. So yes copying single files out of this massive header-only library is a very bad idea.

@talonmies thanks for the help, took me a whole day to install arch linux system because CUDA upgrade went wrong in the original ubuntu system.

@paleonix Great appreciation for the provided info.

@riversandroads Please consider accepting my answer below (green check-mark below the answer score un the upper left of the answer) to mark your question as answered.

As pointed out in the comments by talonmies, universal_ APIs are relatively recent additions to Thrust compared to the basic host_ and device_ APIs. They shipped in February 2021 with Thrust v1.12 which is included in CUDA Toolkit v11.4 and Nvidia HPC SDK v21.3.
You can however still get the whole of Thrust from GitHub to use a newer version of Thrust with an older version of CUDA. See Getting The Thrust Source Code (emphasis mine):

The CUDA Toolkit provides a recent release of the Thrust source code
in include/thrust. This will be suitable for most users.
Users that wish to contribute to Thrust or try out newer features
should recursively clone the Thrust Github repository:
git clone --recursive https://github.com/NVIDIA/thrust.git


The most recent versions of Thrust are not in that archived Thrust repository, but in the newer CCCL repository, which contains its own Getting Started - Users (emphasis mine):

GitHub
Users who want to stay on the cutting edge of CCCL development are
encouraged to use CCCL from GitHub. Using a newer version of CCCL with
an older version of the CUDA Toolkit is supported, but not the other
way around. For complete information on compatibility between CCCL and
the CUDA Toolkit, see our platform support.
Everything in CCCL is header-only, so cloning and including it in a
simple project is as easy as the following:
git clone https://github.com/NVIDIA/cccl.git
nvcc -Icccl/thrust -Icccl/libcudacxx/include -Icccl/cub main.cu -o main


Note
Use -I and not -isystem to avoid collisions with the CCCL headers implicitly included by nvcc from the CUDA Toolkit. All CCCL
headers use #pragma system_header to ensure warnings will still be
silenced as if using -isystem, see
#527 for more information.


Both of the referenced README files also contain further information on CMake usage.
